# yii2 ExportMenu results empty page if columns > 10

Tags: yii2, export-to-csv

I'm using [kartik\export\ExportMenu](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-export) to provide csv exports.
If I want to export approx. more that 10 columns it results just a empty page with no error. Also the yii error log has no entry. With less columns it works.

I tried the following settings but none of them solved it:

1. 'batchSize' => .. tried from 100 to 1000
2. 'streamAfterSave' => false

In case of streaming after file creation it creates any empty file (0B).

Any ideas? Thanks.

--- snip ---

```
<?php
$fullExportMenu = ExportMenu::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'emptyText' => 'Keine Daten verfügbar.',
            'fontAwesome' => true,
            'filename' => 'Webshop_Produkte',
            'showColumnSelector' => false,
            //'noExportColumns' => [0,1]
            //'pjaxContainerId' => 'kv-pjax-container',
            'dropdownOptions' => [
                'label' => 'Alle Daten',
                'class' => 'btn btn-default'
            ],
            'batchSize' => 500,
            //'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_POPUP,
            'stream' => false,
            'streamAfterSave' => false,
            'afterSaveView' => '@app/views/webshop-product/download',
            'folder' => '@app/web/downloads',
            //'linkPath' => '/downloads',
            //'exportConfig' => $exportConfig, 
]);

echo $fullExportMenu . ' ' .
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'pjax' => true,
    'pjaxSettings' => ['options' => ['id' => 'kv-pjax-container']],
    'panel' => [
        'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
        'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> Datei Export</h3>',
    ],
    // set a label for default menu
    'export' => [
        'label' => 'Aktuelle Seite',
        'fontAwesome' => true,
    ],
    // your toolbar can include the additional full export menu
    'toolbar' => [
        '{export}',
        // $fullExportMenu,
        ['content' =>
            Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>', ['index'], [
                'data-pjax' => 0,
                'class' => 'btn btn-default',
                'title' => Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Reset Grid')
            ])
            . ' ' .
            Html::submitButton('Tabelle leeren', ['name' => 'truncate', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
                'data-confirm' => 'Wollen Sie wirklich die Tabelle leeren?'
                . 'Achtung: Löschen kann nicht rückgänig gemacht werden.'
            ])
            . ' ' .
            Html::submitButton('Alles', ['name' => 'download', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
                'data-confirm' => 'Wollen Sie wirklich alles exportieren?'
            ])
        ],
    ]
]);
?>
```

--- snap ---

Comment: show the code please